# what meta tag is requires for sharing to image on twitter,pintrest,and facebook and how to work with addthis share button

Tags: facebook, twitter, meta, addthis, api-key

Thanks to given attention on my question

I am quite new to use add this, i want to share my image on twitter and Pinterest but am not able to do this,i used meta tag for the facebook and twitter.

one thing more i have created app on twitter and facebook which provide me appid and api key where i use these.

I goggled a lot but i did not get reliable source which can help me,

Please provide any solution for this problem

my meta tag are fallowing

for facebook

```
   <meta name="og:site_name" content="Street2media" />

    <meta name="og:title" content="Street2media Image" />
    <meta name="og:description" content=" Watch the AddThis Tour video this the image of a city .Download this city image from the site s2m." /> 

    <meta name="fb:app_id" content="[645268322218331]" />
  <!-- This is the api key for the  twitter--> 
    <meta name="og:description" content="StreetToMedia Image to show" />
<!-- This is the image that will be associated with this content. It should be greater than 50x50 -->  
    <meta name="og:image" content="@ViewBag.FileContent" />

    <meta name="og:url" content="http://127.0.0.1:81/"/>
```

and for twitter

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing everything just fine. I don't know what `@ViewBag.FileContent` stands or but if its a URL to an image available on the internet you should be fine.

I did however notice that your `og:url` is `127.0.0.1:81` which doesn't seem to be a URL available to the public internet. Facebook cannot fetch open graph data from a site that is only available to your local space. so you'll have to push the code to a live server to test it.